# Coding remove() function for a Binary Tree

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

I'm in a data structures class and we have to code a Binary Tree (not a Binary Search Tree). I have like 90% of it working but I'm having trouble getting my remove() function to work.

For reference, we're making a class BinaryTree that must have the following functions

```
template <class ItemType>
class BinaryTree {
    private:
     std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<ItemType>> rootptr;

    protected:
     // Removes the target value from the tree
     virtual std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<ItemType>
     removeValue(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<ItemType>> subTreePtr,
                  const ItemType& target, bool isSuccessful);

     // Copies values up the tree to overwrite value in current
     // node until a leaf is reached; the leaf is then removed,
     // since its value is stored in the parent.
     std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<ItemType>>
     moveValuesUpTree(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<ItemType>>
                      subTreePtr);

      // other { working } methods

    public:
     // Removes specified item from the tree
     bool remove(const ItemType& data);

     // other { working } methods
}
```

The interface for the BinaryNode class (which was provided to us) is:

```
template <class ItemType>
class BinaryNode {
    private:
     ItemType item;
     std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<ItemType>> leftChildPtr;
     std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<ItemType>> rightChildPtr;
    public:
     // returns true if node has no children
     bool isLeaf() const;

     // other typical methods (constructors, getters, setters)
}
```

So far I've tried the following implementation for my moveValuesUpTree function:

```
std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<ItemType>> BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::
    moveValuesUpTree(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<ItemType>>
                     subTreePtr) {

    if(subTreePtr) {
        if(!subTreePtr->isLeaf()) {
            if(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr()) {
                subTreePtr->setItem(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr()
                                    ->getItem());
                moveValuesUpTree(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr());
            } else if(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr()) {
                subTreePtr->setItem(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr()
                                    ->getItem());
                moveValuesUpTree(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr());
            } // end if
        } // end if
    } // end if
    return subTreePtr;
} // end moveValuesUpTree
```

This function works in moving the values up the tree. I was thinking that in coding the removeValue() function I could just move the value of the node I want to remove to the bottom of the tree and then delete it (that way it's always a leaf and you don't have to worry about reconnecting any nodes), but the moveValuesUpTree functions erases the value that I want to get rid of. Is there any way to preserve this value in the recursive moveValuesUpTree function above and then store it in the leaf? Or is there a better way to go about using the two protected methods in conjunction to remove a value?

Thanks!

Edit: The moveValuesUpTree function doesn't get rid of the node -- just the value. So for example, a call of moveValuesUpTree(2) on a tree whose (postorder) output is 74625381 would be 77645831.

Comment: _"...the moveValuesUpTree functions erases the value that I want to get rid of."_ What's the problem?

Comment: @Beta edited post to clarify

Comment: @BalsamicVinegar oh that nick name of yours, BalsamicVinegar +10 HP and restores +1 Mana. :)

Comment: *I have like 90% of it working* It's *always* that last <expletive deleted> 10% that's the problem. It's almost as bad as the last 1%.

Comment: Is this a correct algorithm? Normally there is a rotation step.

Comment: I don't really understand what the question is. Is this supposed to be an arbitrary binary tree without any invariants? No ordering, no balancing?

Comment: @user207421 which algorithm? Everything I've coded so far has been working, I'm not sure what you mean by a 'rotation step'.

Comment: The comment in the declaration of `moveValuesUpTree` says "...the leaf is then removed,..." Apart from the barbaric use of the passive mode, this seems to suggest that you intend that the function remove the leaf. Is that your intention? Your implementation doesn't seem to remove any node.

Comment: I wouldnt bother moving the value to the leef, i would just check in the moveValueUpTree function if the left/right child is a leef before calling the function again and if its a leef just destroy the node(since you already have the child value inside the current node)

Comment: @Beta It needs to. I don't know how to write the remove method.

Comment: @BalsamicVinegar why dont you just do like i said in my comment ? it would work perfectly and fix your issue.

Comment: @Matriac Ah, I think I see what you mean. I'll try it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of moving the value to the last leaf and then delete the leaf, you should delete it when you are moving the values up since it is at this moment you will find the leaf and will know his exact position. What I would suggest is to test if the left or right child of the current node is a leaf and if it is, delete it since you already move the value of it in the current node.

```
std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<ItemType>> BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::
moveValuesUpTree(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<ItemType>>subTreePtr) {

    if(subTreePtr) {
        if(!subTreePtr->isLeaf()) {
            if(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr()) {
                subTreePtr->setItem(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr()->getItem());

                if(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr()->isLeaf())
                    //Delete left child here
                else
                    moveValuesUpTree(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr());
              } else if(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr()) {
                subTreePtr->setItem(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr()->getItem());

                if(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr()->isLeaf())
                    //Delete right child here
                else
                     moveValuesUpTree(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr());
            } // end if
        } // end if
    } // end if
    return subTreePtr;
} // end moveValuesUpTree
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Matriac, I fixed the problem by editing moveValuesUpTree

```
std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<ItemType>> BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::
    moveValuesUpTree(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<ItemType>>
                     subTreePtr) {

    if(subTreePtr) {
        if(!subTreePtr->isLeaf()) {
            if(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr()) {
                subTreePtr->setItem(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr()
                                    ->getItem());
                if(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr()->isLeaf()) {
                    subTreePtr->setLeftChildPtr(nullptr);
                } else {
                    moveValuesUpTree(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr());
                }
             } else if(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr()) {
            subTreePtr->setItem(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr()
                                ->getItem());
                if(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr()->isLeaf()) {
                    subTreePtr->setRightChildPtr(nullptr);
                } else {
                    moveValuesUpTree(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr());
                } // end if
            } // end if
        } // end if
    } // end if
    return subTreePtr;
} // end moveValuesUpTree
```